# Weirdness with regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
"(?<=L).+?(?=;)"
```

Which is supposed to match anything between L and ;

I'm using it on this text

```
"(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/lang/String;"
```

and I'm getting the matches as

```
"java/net/URL"
";)Ljava/lang/String"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are expected. The second match is beginning at the "L" in "URL". Since you're using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), the match isn't "consuming" the `L` and `;`. You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
"L(.+?);"
```

so your desired matches are in the first subpattern and the `L` and `;` won't be available for later matching.

Comment: Ha, I didn't notice the L in URL.

Comment: Shouldn't the `.+?` part consume the L away so it isn't available to the lookbehind of the second match?

Comment: @AndreKR Yes, the match includes the `L`, but it's not consuming the `L` and `;` as delimiters. The problem is caused by the lookbehind. The match ends with the `L`, so it starts looking for the next match at `;`. (We actually should start looking for the next match _after_ that `;` delimiter.) Firstly, it checks to see if there is an `L` before that point, which there is, even though we don't want to count that one.

Comment: So the lookbehind uses the *original input* and not what is left of it after the first match?

Comment: @AndreKR Correct. Matching doesn't change the input string, but it moves the pointer along. If you've matched something, it starts looking for the next match at that point because it's already looked at the previous stuff. But a lookbehind assertion allows you to add a "was this preceded by ___?" condition, essentially allowing you to "look behind" your current position just for the sake of verification.